# Has the National Near Earth Object Preparedness Strategy and Action Plan seen any action?

Tags: nasa, near-earth-asteroid, united-states

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41535/12102) to *Does NASA have an end-of-the-world policy?* mentions the [National Near Earth Object Preparedness Strategy and Action Plan](https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/National-Near-Earth-Object-Preparedness-Strategy-and-Action-Plan-23-pages-1MB.pdf).

Has this plan resulted in any action?

Comment: "When in trouble, when in doubt: run in circles, scream and shout."  Which is to say, there's always the the evaluation matrix of "level of probability" vs. "seriousness of outcome" ; said matrix to be used to decide how much time&money&resource is worth spending on events with  X probability.

Comment: Appropriate user name for this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the usual collection of overly dramatic news reports about this branch of NASA finding and tracking near-misses:

[express.co.uk](https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/1237963/Asteroid-alert-NASA-tracks-rock-wipe-out-continent-hit-Earth-approach-asteroid-news)   reports  a tracked object that came within 0.03860 AU. It's not clear when NASA first detected it.

[USAToday](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2019/04/29/asteroid-strike-nasa-conducts-drill-end-world/3615392002/) for a simulation drill that was run in mid-2019,

> as a tabletop exercise Monday-Friday at the 2019 Planetary Defense
>   Conference in  College Park, Maryland

Closer to reality:

A [NASA](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/sbag/meetings/jun2019/presentations/Fast.pdf) update briefing with lots of colorful charts. Some examples:
[image]

[image]

[image]

So not only are tracking methods and capabilities being upgraded, but long-range planning and design of possible deflector systems continue.  Bruce Willis approves.

Comment: @uhoh will attempt to do so  once I get rid of my stack of VeryImportantMeetings(TM)

Comment: excellent, thank you!

Comment: A tabletop exercise is run at each of the biennial Planetary Defense Conferences involving the conference participants; past conferences links are [here](http://pdc.iaaweb.org/?q=content/past-conferences). NASA and FEMA run joint tabletop exercises roughly every year, reports of previous exercises are at the bottom of the [PDCO Supporting Documents page](https://www.nasa.gov/planetarydefense/supporting_documents)